# Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class in tomcat 9

Tags: java, tomcat

I am new to Tomcat server. We are upgrading version of tomcat 6 to tomcat 9 and I am facing below error.

> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup Servlet [invoker] in web application threw load() exception
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.servlets.InvokerServlet

I did a lot of search and I found that server.xml and web.xml needs to be modified. But I am not sure what modification is required. Please suggest.

EDIT:

@Veke mentioned that invokerServlet is not supposed to be in tomcat 9. I did some digging and found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20759311/11508196

I have made these changes but It is showing below error, where com.package.MyListenerClass is my Listener class:

```
Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.package.MyListenerClass] java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: do you have  `<servlet-name>invoker</servlet-name` in server.xml?

Answer (score 0):

InvokerServlet is not supported in version 9. Learn more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

You can use `@WebServlet("/xyz")` annotation Ref: [webservlet](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html)